# Mysql - Select next x records even if reaching rowset end

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an ID field, unique, autoincremental.

I need to, given certain ID, retrieve next 3 records even when given ID is the last one.

Table:

```
ID       
1         
2         
3         
4         
5         
6         
7
```

**What I need:**

```
Given ID is 1 => retrieve 2,3,4  
Given ID is 2 => retrieve 3,4,5
```

.....

```
Given ID is 5 => retrieve 6,7,1  
Given ID is 6 => retrieve 7,1,2  
Given ID is 7 => retrieve 1,2,3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try for a pure SQL solution:

```
SELECT id
FROM  
   (  ( SELECT *, 0 AS chck
        FROM tableX
        WHERE id > @givenID
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 3
      )
    UNION ALL
      ( SELECT *, 1 
        FROM tableX
        WHERE id <= @givenID      -- just in case of a small table (< 3 rows) 
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 3
      )
   ) AS t
ORDER BY chck, id
LIMIT 3 ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cf13/12).

---

The query is basically an improvement on [Jehad's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108023/mysql-select-next-x-records-even-if-reaching-rowset-end/108046#108046). It doesn't use a variable (`@rank`) and the two internal `LIMIT`s will result in improved efficiency on a large table.

Assuming there is an index on `id`, the two subqueries will use the index and only need to fetch 3 ids and 3 rows each from the table. The external table (`t`) after the `UNION` will have a maximum of 6 rows to sort.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer not using stored procedures, here is my way:

```
set @my_id=7; 
set @rank=0; 
select id from 
    (  
        (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id>@my_id order by id) 
        union 
        (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id < @my_id order by id)
    ) my_table 
limit 3;
```

You change the value of @my_id accordingly.

```
Examples:
select * from t;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

set @my_id=7; 
set @rank=0; 
select id from 
    ->     (  
    ->         (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id>@my_id order by id) 
    ->         union 
    ->         (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id < @my_id order by id)
    ->     ) my_table 
    -> limit 3;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

set @my_id=5; 
set @rank=0; 

select id from 
    ->     (  
    ->         (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id>@my_id order by id) 
    ->         union 
    ->         (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id < @my_id order by id)
    ->     ) my_table 
    -> limit 3;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    1 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

set @my_id=1; 
set @rank=0; 
select id from 
    ->     (  
    ->         (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id>@my_id order by id) 
    ->         union 
    ->         (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as x from t where id < @my_id order by id)
    ->     ) my_table 
    -> limit 3;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started. The procedure will get the correct rows. It would have been a lot easier if you hadn't wanted to restart at the beginning when you reached the end. :)

```
 delimiter $$
 create procedure getRows(in inID int)
 begin
      declare maxID int;
      declare IDPlusOne int;
      declare IDPlusTwo int;
      declare IDPlusThree int;

      declare strIDs varchar(100);
      declare strSQL varchar(8000);

      set maxID = (select max(id) from testTable);
      set inID = (case when inID > maxID then inID = maxID else inID end);
      set IDPlusOne = (case when maxID < inID + 1 then inID + 1 - maxID else inID + 1 end);
      set IDPlusTwo = (case when maxID < inID + 2 then inID + 2 - maxID else inID + 2 end);
      set IDPlusThree = (case when maxID < inID + 3 then inID + 3 - maxID else inID + 3 end);

      set strIDs = (select concat(IDPlusOne,',',IDPlusTwo,',',IDPlusThree));
      set strSQL = (select concat('select * from testTable where ID in (',strIDs,')'));

      set @s = strSQL;
      prepare stmt from @s;
      execute stmt;

 end$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a `Stored Procedure` where you can send the `STARD_ID` and the `QUANTITY` of rows.

**Example:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.tbl;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
+----+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL test.rows(6,4);;
+---------+----------+----------+
| STR     | START_ID | QUANTITY |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 6,7,1,2 |        6 |        4 |
+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**`STORED PROCEDURE:`**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `rows`(
IN eID INT(6),
IN eQTY INT(6))
BEGIN

DECLARE vQTY INT(6) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE vCOUNTER INT(6) DEFAULT 0;

SET vCOUNTER    =0;
SET vQTY        =eQTY;
SET @START_ID   =eID;
SET @OUTPUT_STR ="";

WHILE vCOUNTER<vQTY DO
    # [ IF THE COUNTER = 0, SET THE @START_ID LIKE @NEXT_ID ]
    IF (vCOUNTER=0) THEN
        SET @NEXT_ID=@START_ID;
    ELSE
        SET @NEXT_ID=(SELECT ID FROM test.tbl WHERE ID>@NEXT_ID ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0,1);
    END IF;
    # [ IF THERE'S NOT ANY ID GREATER THAN THE LAST, RESTART ]
    IF (@NEXT_ID IS NULL) THEN
        SET @NEXT_ID=(SELECT ID FROM test.tbl ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0,1);
    END IF;
    # [ INCREMENTING COUNTER ] 
    SET vCOUNTER=vCOUNTER+1;
    # [ OUTPUT STRING ]
    SET @OUTPUT_STR=CONCAT(@OUTPUT_STR,@NEXT_ID,IF(vCOUNTER=vQTY,"",","));
END WHILE;
# [ OUTPUT QUERY ]
SELECT @OUTPUT_STR AS STR,eID AS START_ID,vQTY AS QUANTITY;
END
```