# Perform mysql limited select that wraps when it reaches the end of table

Tags: mysql, select

I want to grab the next 2 rows from a table after a given id. This code works nicely however if the rows being selected right at the end of the database I need the select to wrap around so for instance in a table of rows 0 to N I will at some point want to pull out rows N and 0 and then a bit later pull out 0 and 1. Is it possible to make a MYSQL select wrap around like this?

```
SELECT `promo_id` 
FROM `promotions` 
WHERE (`expiry_date` >= '2017-03-21' AND `promo_id` > (SELECT `promo_id`  FROM `promoted_questions` WHERE `promo_id` = 8))
ORDER BY `promo_id` ASC
LIMIT 2
```

UPDATE for clarity:

At the moment my code just returns up to the end of the table rather than wrapping back around to get the first rows again. Here's an example of what I want:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I run the code above with the starting ID as 2 then get IDs 3 and 4 back - perfect. If I run it with the starting ID as 4 then all I get back is 5, not so perfect as I was 5 and 1. Likewise, if I use starting ID 5 then I want 1 and 2 back from the database.

Comment: so, what is Your problem? potential error - subquery could return more than 1 rows?

Comment: Ah, sorry. it just returns upto the end of the table and doesn't wrap to the beginning again. I'll edit the question

Comment: This may give you a nice hint: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108023/mysql-select-next-x-records-even-if-reaching-rowset-end/108046#108046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set a [rextester](http://rextester.com/QLBG12416) example whith this sample data:

```
drop table if exists promotions;
create table if not exists promotions (promo_id int, expiry_date timestamp);
insert into promotions values
(1, '20170101'),(2, '20170101'),(3, '20170101'),(4, '20170101'),(5, '20170101');
```

IMHO you should add two additional records and then limit final result to two rows. Use a UNION with your query and an addition query that simply returns the two first rows of promotions table.

Note: Add parentheses to both queries or you'll get an error.

```
(select  promo_id
from     promotions
where    promo_id > 4
order by promo_id
limit    2)
union
(select  promo_id
from     promotions
order by promo_id
limit    2)
limit 2
;
```

The final result:

```
promo_id  |expiry_date
----------|--------------------
   5      | 01.01.2017 00:00:00
   1      | 01.01.2017 00:00:00
```

**Using you query**

```
(SELECT `promo_id` 
 FROM `promotions` 
 WHERE (`expiry_date` >= '2017-03-21' AND `promo_id` > (SELECT `promo_id`  FROM `promoted_questions` WHERE `promo_id` = 8))
 ORDER BY `promo_id` ASC
 LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `promo_id`
 FROM `promoted_questions`
 ORDER BY `promo_id` ASC
 LIMIT 2
)
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: just will need little adopt, because for some reason @SimonBarker fetch promo_id as result of select from second table (think some business logic under this).

Comment: @a_vlad I'm not sure to understand you, is that what you mean? I've added SimonBarker original query.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution - will try tomorrow and accept

Comment: @McNets - SELECT `promo_id`  FROM `promoted_questions`, `promoted_questions` - is not `promotions`, I mean - Your query idea correct, but `promo_id` - in original query taken from other table

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`.  And cross your fingers that the order of the union is preserved.

Comment: @RickJames Is there no guarentee with `UNION/ALL` that the order will be preserved?

Comment: The only way to preserve order is using ORDER BY promo_id DESC, this means that if you fetch 5,1,2, the final result will be 5, 2

Comment: @SimonBarker - In general, if you don't say `ORDER BY`, SQL and the Optimizer is free to deliver the rows in any order it chooses.  The inner orders _may_ be ignored when doing the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

It gets messy to get the order right:

```
SELECT  promo_id            -- extra SELECT, to avoid displaying `sequence`
    FROM  ( 
            (   SELECT  1 AS sequence,   -- for making sure these come first
                        promo_id
                    from  promotions
                    where  promo_id > 4  -- (or use a subquery)
                    order by  promo_id
                    LIMIT  2             -- last 2 (or fewer)
            ) union
            (   SELECT  2 AS sequence,
                        promo_id
                    from  promotions
                    order by  promo_id
                    LIMIT  2             -- first 2 (in case of wrap)
            ) 
            ORDER BY  sequence, promo_id
            LIMIT  2 
          ) AS x
```

(I hope I got the proper parentheses.)